# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: topk$topkMapper.<init>() : MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, runtime-error

I keep getting this message when I try to run my code using Hadoop:
At first I was missing the static tag but now I have that added for my mapper and reducer but I keep getting this error. Any tips on how to fix it?

```
2021-11-26 15:37:57,852 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1692)) - Task Id : 
    attempt_1637960282016_0002_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
    Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: topk$topkMapper.<init>()
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1845)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: topk$topkMapper.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: If more information is needed please let me know! thanks!

Comment: It's best you include more details, JRE version, packages you're using etc. Wild guess says it's a versioning missmatch